# Simultaenous Tank with Inlet and Outlet Pipe

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A tank is filled through its inlet pipe and then emptied through is outlet pipe in a total of 8 hours. If water enteres through its inlet pipe and simulataenously allowed to leave through its outlet pipe. The tank is filled in 7.5 hours. How long it will take to fill the tank with the outlet pipe closed?

The answer is 3 hours.

I have tried doing

```
1/A - 1/8 = 1/7.5
```

But i always get 3.87o. Any Hint?

Comment: It seems the $8$ hours is the sum of two distinct processes. I read the problem as saying for $x$ hours we fill the tank with the outlet closed, then for $8 - x$ hours we let the tank drain without putting anything in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tank has a volume of $V$ and the inlet pipe can transport a volume of $r_i$ per hour, the outlet pipe a volume $r_o$ per hour.

The first information given can be modeled as
$$
t \, r_i = V = (8-t) \, r_o \quad (*)
$$
The second information given leads to
$$
7.5 (r_i - r_o) = V \quad (**)
$$
The filling with closed output is just
$$
t \, r_i = V
$$ 
We need to solve for $t$.

We know from setting the right hand side of $(*)$ equal to the left hand side from $(**)$: 
$$
(8-t) r_o = 7.5 r_i - 7.5 r_o \iff \\
\frac{15.5 - t}{7.5} r_0 = r_i = \left(\frac{8}{t} - 1\right) r_0
$$
where we solved $(*)$ for $r_i$. This holds in case of $r_o \ne 0$ if
$$
\frac{15.5 - t}{7.5} = \left(\frac{8}{t} - 1\right) \iff \\
23 - t = \frac{60}{t} \iff \\
23 t - t^2 = 60 \iff \\
t^2 - 23 t + 60 = 0
$$
This quadratic equation in $t$ can be solved as usual:
$$
(t - 11.5)^2 = 11.5^2 - 60 = 72.25 \iff \\
t = 11.5 \pm \sqrt{72.25} \iff \\
t = 3 \vee t = 20
$$
Only $t \le 8$ is feasible, so $t=3$ hours is the solution.

BTW this gives $r_i = (5/3) r_o$. And $r_o = V/5$ and thus $r_i = V/3$.